# Url Rewrite to new url

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, web-config

```
  <rule name="WC2018" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^product/sb/sales.htm" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="product/sb/market/sales.htm" />
  </rule>
```

Above is the url rewrite that i do, the original link is

> product/sb/sales.htm

I need to rewrite it to

> product/sb/market/sales.htm

But it does not work. I not sure what went wrong.

Comment: What is your application stack?

Comment: @Yasir i'm using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rules :

```
<rule name="rule 1k" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^product/sb/market/sales.htm$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/product/sb/sales.htm"  />
</rule>
```